# what's the difference between these two solr queries?

Tags: solr, lucene

What's the difference between these two solr queries:

1. NOT name:*
2. NOT name:[* TO *]

Both of the two can return some results.But I can't discriminate the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on reading the documentation for SOLR query.

> NOT name:[* TO *]

removes all documents with the name and whatever value name contains, as shown on this documentation: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

> NOT name:*

removes all member fields belonging to name.

NOT is a keyword reserve in removing results of whatever field + value. They show you different results because if you specify a value to `NOT name:[* TO *]`, you are bound to get results that exclude from the rule you've specified.

Keep in mind that SOLR query employs certain regex rules.

Comment: This is a valuable resource to look into http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html